# Clear all queryParams with new Router v3 Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Angular2 router navigation (router 3.0.0-alpha.7) with query parameters.

I can easily navigate to a route with a queryParam with this line:

```
this._router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: {redirect: 'route1'}});
```

In the '/login' component, I do some login which will redirect to the `redirect` route, namely route1 here. However, after the redirection, the `redirect` query parameters stays in the URL, i.e. I'm now at page `/route1?redirect=route1`. I want to remove the redirect parameter here.

Moreover, if I then navigate to another page with the same `redirect` queryParam, it doesn't overwrite the previous one, but adds another `?redirect=...` in the url. Namely:

```
this._router.navigate(['/another-route'], {queryParams: {redirect:'route2'}});
```

leads me to `/another-route?redirect=route2?redirect=route1`

Is it possible to clear the queryParams when navigating between routes?
I tried `this._router.navigate(['/route1'], {queryParams: {redirect: null}});`, or `{queryParams: null}` etc but no success.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I struggled with this as well. You would expect the router to clear query params by default when navigating to another route...

You can do either

```
this._router.navigate(['/route1'], {queryParams: {}});
```

or

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('/route1');
```

or when using `routerLink`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/applications']" [queryParams]="{}"> Applications</a>
```

Comment: How can I achieve the same with routerLinks?
`<a [routerLink]="['/applications'], { queryParams: {} }"> Applications</a>` throws a parse error. Docs are missing this.

Comment: I'll add this to the answer

Comment: ...so the solution is to append empty query params *everywhere* a link is used? That is..... horrifying....

Answer (score 7):

Actually ... you should NOT "*expect the router to clear query params*".

Clearly you DO expect that. But that's because you don't know about an important router design decision ... probably because, unfortunately, *we haven't told you about it in the docs yet*.  We're working on correcting that now.

**QueryParams** are for parameters that are global across navigations; they do not change.

**MatrixParams** are for parameters that belong to the current navigation; these do change.

What belongs in global `QueryParams`? Stuff that comes from the server are candidates. Like auth tokens that belong on every interaction.

But required **route params** (the `:id` in `customer/:id`) and **optional matrix params** (like the `;name=Jo*` in `/customers;name=Jo*`) are local to one navigation.  That's how you might specify a navigation for customers with an optional name filter.

Whether or not you agree with this approach, it is fundamental to the v.3 router design.

I suggest adjusting your expectations rather than fighting it.

Comment: When can we expect additional details regarding the MatrixParams? @Ward

Comment: Some of what that is in the updated Router chapter under the [Query Parameters](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters) section.

But the author and I think we can be more clear. We'll update it once again ... very soon.

Comment: thanks @Ward, i'll keep an eye out for the updated router documentation

Comment: @Ward is that related to the OAuth bugs that were filed on github? I actually think its very weird to do this by default, and it is extremely confusing.  I understand that it's a design decision and appreciate that there are probably a *ton* of caveats I'm not privvy to, but the standard way of the internet has always been to explicitly add query params to a URL, not have them just added for you. At the moment, the RouterLink directive is appending query params to everything in my application, meaning I have to turn it off explicitly everywhere it's used. Or is there a way around it?

Comment: A case in point at the moment is deep linking, it seems to sometimes keep params/hashes around, other times not. Really not sure what's up with that... :/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `preserveQueryParams: false` parameter to ignore query params

```
this.router.navigate(['target'], {preserveQueryParams: false});
```

Comment: Looks more neat