# How do I wipe a persisting query string

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a Component that displays a paged list, being the current page identified in the query string like `.../Listing?page=3`.

The first element of this list is an anchor with a `routeLink` to a Component that displays that line information:

`<a [routerLink]="['Item', item.id]" routerLinkActive="active">{{ item.id }}</a>`

When I click the link the URL is updated to `.../Listing/Item/11?page=3`.

Is there a way to specify in the anchor that the query string should be wiped?

Comment: Same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242584/clear-all-queryparams-with-new-router-v3-angular2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the anchor to include a empty object as query string parameter makes the page to disappear.

`<a [routerLink]="['Item', item.id]" routerLinkActive="active" [queryParams]="{}">{{ item.id }}</a>`

Generate the url `.../.../Listing/Item/11`